# The generic type information of fields in traits are missing?

Tags: generics, scala, morphia, traits

I found this problem when I use `Morphia` in scala. It checks the fields of a class by reflection, and get necessary type information for mapping.

But if I use `traits`, and define some collection fields, the generic type information will be lost, which cause Morphia can't get enough information, and throw exceptions.

See my code:

```
trait HasTags {
    @Reference
    var tags: java.util.List[Tag] = new java.util.ArrayList[Tag]()  // the generic type is Tag
}

class Question extends Entity with HasTags {

}
```

I compiled the scala file, and get some java class files. Then I use java decompiler to see the content of the java byte codes:

```
public class Question extends Entity implements HasTags {
      @Reference
      private java.util.List tags;
}
```

You can see there is no `Tag` here, so Morphia will fail.

I used `scala 2.8.1`. Is there any way to fix it?

---

**UPDATE**

@extempore said, maybe `javap` doesn't display that `Tag` information.

But I used a program called [Java Decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/jd-gui/downloads), not `javap`.

I tried this code:

```
class Question extends Entity with HasTags {
    @Reference
    var tags2: java.util.List[Tag] = new java.util.ArrayList()
}
```

And see the byte code in `Java Decompiler`, it displays:

```
public class Question extends Entity implements HasTags {
      @Reference
      private java.util.List tags;
      @Reference
      private java.util.List<models.Tag> tags2;
}
```

We can see the `tags2` contains `Tag`, but `tags` doesn't.

And the interface `HasTags` is:

```
public abstract interface HasTags extends ScalaObject
{
  public abstract List<Tag> tags();

  @TraitSetter
  public abstract void tags_$eq(List<Tag> paramList);
}
```

We can see, the return value of method `tags()` is `List<Tag>`, but the field `tags` is not.

Since morphia get the information by fields, it can't work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how javap displays things.  It doesn't mean the signature isn't present.

```
scala> classOf[HasTags].getMethod("tags").getGenericReturnType
res0: java.lang.reflect.Type = java.util.List<Tag>
```

That's how you know it is.  You can also see it in the constant pool.

```
const #3 = Asciz    tags;
const #4 = Asciz    ()Ljava/util/List;;
const #5 = Asciz    ()Ljava/util/List<LTag;>;;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what else to show: it can't say "Tag" in this output unless the signature is present.  Field and method.

```
% cat a.scala 
class Tag
class Ref {
  var tags: java.util.List[Tag] = new java.util.ArrayList()
}
% scalac281 a.scala 
% scala281
Welcome to Scala version 2.8.1.final (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_22).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> classOf[Ref].getDeclaredField("tags").getGenericType 
res0: java.lang.reflect.Type = java.util.List<Tag>

scala> classOf[Ref].getMethod("tags").getGenericReturnType 
res1: java.lang.reflect.Type = java.util.List<Tag>
```